# What happens when my box is full?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-mansion-monster-manor

Since I tag the same two people three times a day, I'm creating a crapton of rooms and loot. I'm on floor 13 and already have over 80 items in my 99-capacity box. What happens if I get loot and there's no room for it in either my pocket or my box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the inevitable happened, and somewhat as expected, anything collected while both pocket and box is full is just thrown away.